# remove plugin on specific template page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filter

I am using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pdf24-post-to-pdf/ pdf generator plugin for my site, but I only want it present on certain pages.

How can I remove it from all pages except a certain template I allow?

I believe this can be done with filters, but I have googled and googled and can't seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible without modifying the plugin source code. That would be a nice security issue, IMO.

Plugins are files simply included on the loading process. At least, there's no hook I could find on WordPress source code for you to interfere in this behavior. Take a look just above the [`plugins_loaded`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/plugins_loaded?version=3.2&file=wp-settings.php) hook, and the [`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins`](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/load.php.source.html#l468) function.

What you can try to do, instead, is just modifying the plugin with the condition you need. In the top of the `pdf24.php` file, just below the standard comments, put:

```
if (!condition_met())
    return;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think you are right, and that is the right way to handle it.